# Cypher query to find avg age in a path

Tags: neo4j

In the query below how do I find the average age of users present in the path:

```
start begin=node:Nodes(Name="User_2"), end=node:Nodes(Name="User_32")

match p = begin--()--end

return extract(n in nodes(p): n.Age);
```

Answer (score 2):

in cypher 1.8 just fixing your first query:

```
start begin=node:Nodes(Name="User_2"), end=node:Nodes(Name="User_32")
match begin--middle--end
where has(middle.Age)
return sum(middle.Age) / count(middle);
```

i believe, however, that you ask for all users from User_2 to User_32:

```
start n=node(*)
where has(n.Age) and Id(n)>1 and Id(n)<33
return sum(n.Age) / count(n);
```

but in last case, if you are asking for all users in the path between User1 and User32:

```
start begin=node:Nodes(Name="User_2"), end=node:Nodes(Name="User_32")
match p=begin-[*..]-end
with extract(n in nodes(p): n)
where has(n.Age)
return sum(n.Age) / count(n);
```

**edit:** i just found that you can replace the *sum(n.Age) / count(n);* simply with **avg(n.Age)**

Comment: This is not the avg age over a path, but rather the avg age over the result set.

Answer (score 2):

So, in 1.9 you can now do this with `reduce`.

```
start begin=node:Nodes(Name="User_2"), end=node:Nodes(Name="User_32")
match p = begin--()--end
return reduce(total=0, n in nodes(p): total + n.Age) / length(p) as avgAge;
```